# differentiate between two input boxes max and min value

Tags: angularjs

```
<section class="col col-4">
    <label>Min Stock Level</label>
    <label class="input">
        <input type="text" name="minStock" min="0" ng-model="item.MinStockLevel" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,6})?$/" required />
        <span ng-show="myForm.minStock.$dirty && myForm.minStock.$invalid">
            <span style="color:green" ng-show="myForm.minStock.$error.required">Price is Required</span>
            <span style="color: red" ng-show="myForm.minStock.$error.pattern">Not Valid</span>
         </span>
     </label>
 </section>
```

this is first text box where enter min value.

```
<section class="col col-4">
     <label>Max Stock Level</label>
     <label class="input">
         <input type="text" name="maxStock" ng-     model="item.MaxStockLevel" min=" {{ item.MinStockLevel + 1 }}" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,6})?$/" required />
          <span ng-show=" myform.maxstock.$dirty && myform.maxstock.$invalid">
              <span style="color:green" ng-show="myForm.maxStock.$error.required">Price is Required</span>
               <span style="color: red" ng-show="myForm.maxStock.$error.pattern">Not Valid</span>
           </span>    
     </label>
 </section>
```

it is second input box. i want to differentiate between two boxes min stock level and max stock level values.  where user can enter max value greater then min value and min value less than max value. how can i validate it?

Comment: so, what exactly do you wish to achieve? apply the min and max condition at the input boxes level?

Comment: yes i want to apply min and max condition on my text boxes or any ng-validation that validate my boxes

Comment: shouldn't you change the input type="text" to input type="number"? Because min and max do not apply on input type text. They're valid on numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue was with input type="text", which should've been input type="number", since min and max apply to numbers, and not text.